# How to draw different vectors in different points in a co-ordination space?

Tags: plotting, graphics

suppose I have four vectors: v1,v2,v3,v4 at the positions (1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1) respectively in position space in xy plane and the two dimensional components are (0.5,-0.5),(0.75,0.1),(0.4,0.6),(-0.5,-0.5) respectively. somebody please help how to make a vector plot with these information?

Answer (score 4):

```
pos = Tuples[{1, -1}, {2}];
vlst = {{0.5, -0.5}, {0.75, 0.1}, {0.4, 0.6}, {-0.5, -0.5}};
colors = {Red, Green, Blue, Orange};

Graphics[MapThread[{ #, PointSize[Large], Point@#2, 
   Thick, Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{#2 , #2 + #3}]} &, {colors, pos, vlst}], 
 Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Graphics[MapThread[{ #, PointSize[Large], Point@#2, 
   Thick, Arrowheads[Large], Translate[ Arrow[{{0, 0}, #3}], #2]} &, {colors, pos, vlst}], 
  Axes -> True, GridLines -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks. The answer is useful

Comment: I have one more query regarding this. Suppose I have thousands of vector defined in thousands points. so it is not possible to define color for individual vectors. Then how to define a color function for the all vectors?

Comment: @atanu, you can use `colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range@Length@pos];` or `colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ 
  Rescale[Norm /@ (pos + vlst)]; ` or `colors=RandomColor[Length@pos]`

Comment: thank you. It works fine..